# NumberFormatException for input string Edittext

Tags: android, kotlin, type-conversion, android-edittext, number-formatting

```
var bmi: Float
if(binding.rbMetric.isChecked){
    bmi = binding.currWeightEdit.text.toString().toFloat() / binding.meterEditText.toString().toFloat().pow(2)
}else{
    bmi = (binding.currWeightEdit.text.toString().toFloat()*703)/ (binding.feetEditText.text.toString().toInt()*12 + binding.inchesEditText.toString().toInt()).toFloat().pow(2)
}
return bmi
```

This code is meant to calculate the BMI for either the metric or imperial unit. The input type of the Editexts weight and meter are numberDecimal and meter,feet are number. The error is: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText{b7d8c80 VFED..CL. ........ 0,0-385,153 #7f0800cc app:id/inches_edit_text aid=1073741832}". How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the first calculation you used

```
binding.meterEditText.toString().toFloat().pow(2)
```

when it should have been

```
binding.meterEditText.text.toString().toFloat().pow(2)
```

So it was calling `toString()` on the EditText view itself. You repeated this error further down where you used `toInt()`.

To make this code less repetitive and error prone, you could use an extension. Also, when using `binding` over and over, it's cleaner to use `with(binding)`.

```
val TextView.textAsFloat: Float get() = text.toString().toFloat()

return with(binding) {
    if (rbMetric.isChecked) {
        currWeightEdit.textAsFloat / meterEditText.textAsFloat.pow(2)
    } else {
        currWeightEdit.textAsFloat * 703 / (feetEditText.textAsFloat * 12 + inchesEditText.textAsFloat).pow(2)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your code on, you are getting editText input in wrong way.

```
var bmi: Float
    if(binding.rbMetric.isChecked){
        //replace below line in your actual code
        binding.meterEditText.text.toString().toFloat().pow(2)
        bmi = binding.currWeightEdit.text.toString().toFloat() / binding.meterEditText.toString().toFloat().pow(2)
    }else{
        //replace below line in your actual code
         binding.inchesEditText.text.toString().toInt()).toFloat().pow(2)
        bmi = (binding.currWeightEdit.text.toString().toFloat()*703)/ (binding.feetEditText.text.toString().toInt()*12 + binding.inchesEditText.toString().toInt()).toFloat().pow(2)
    }
    return bmi
```